# How can a CSS grid use the maximum nested element size to render equally sized columns?

Tags: css, css-grid

[See this fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/npg06kdu/259/)

Consider a grid of words in four columns, with each column being the same width. I can get this with `grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(25%, 1fr));` Most of the time, these will be short words. But there could be a long word which overflows its block:

[image: minmax(25%, 1fr)]

If this were static data, I could have just changed the grid css to `grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(33%, 1fr));` to comfortably fill the space:

[image: minmax(33%, 1fr)]

How can I make the CSS renderer adjust the number of columns for me, making each the same width, using the width of the widest word block in the set?

Comment: I don't think it's possible with only CSS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm surprised that CSS doesn't (as far as I can tell) support this since I think it should be a common use case for wrapping grids. I tinkered until I had a solution with a minimal amount of javascript:

[example fiddle with IIFE](https://jsfiddle.net/9xjfmdb3/66/)

First, we need to find out how wide the widest string (or could be any block element) will be when rendered on the client. `grid-template-columns: repeat(1, max-content);` will do that by arranging the elements in a single column, and all elements get the width of the widest one. After the dimensions are established but before being rendered to the screen, grab any element, compute the number of columns that will fit, then change the CSS for the container to have that many columns + 1fr to make them fill the space:

```
(function(){
  const ul = document.querySelectorAll('ul')[0];
  const ee = [...document.querySelectorAll('li')];
  const max = ee.map(e=>e.offsetWidth).reduce((a,b)=>Math.max(a, b));
  const cols = Math.min(5,Math.floor(ul.offsetWidth/max));
    ul.style.gridTemplateColumns = "repeat("+cols+", 1fr)";
})();
```

This seems to work with no flicker in all evergreen browsers. Angular version I used:

```
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
  const ul: HTMLElement = this.ul.nativeElement;
  let cols: number = 0;
  const w: number = ul.children[0].clientWidth;
  if (w > 0) {
    cols = Math.min(5, Math.floor(ul.offsetWidth / w));
  }
  ul.style.gridTemplateColumns = "repeat(" + cols + ",1fr)";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

As far as I know this is unsolvable with CSS-only, so, I will provide a Javascript-based solution.

First of all, let's find the longest text:

```
let longestText = '';
for (let text of texts) {
    if (longestText.length < text.length) longestText = text;
}
```

Then, you can find that item:

```
let lng = document.querySelectorAll('ul li').filter((item) => item.innerText === longestText)[0].offsetWidth;
```

Then you can divide the whole width that you have at your disposal with `lng`, the value you have just calculated and see how many columns you can have.

Comment: You're counting characters. That will not work because some characters are wider than others.

Comment: @JohnChurchill I'm measuring the element with the longest text. I'm not estimating the size based on character length, but actually measure it. I could measure it for all items, but that will not perform well if it's not necessary.

Comment: Your code is "longestText.length" which is number of characters in the string. By that logic, "iiiii" is wider than "mmmm" but when rendered by the browser it is narrower. (Also, your code is comparing number to string; it will leave longestText to blank, then not find the element.)

Comment: @JohnChurchill you are right in your second point, I have edited my answer accordingly. While your first point is technically true, in reality I do not consider it to be relevant. Texts tend to have varied characters, so it makes sense to win performance without worrying about edge-cases. Yet, if those edge-cases turn out to be important, then of course we can do actual measurements for all items. So, the dangers of my approach is that in some cases, when a text contains wide characters, but a "longer" text contains thinner characters, the grid would not be displayed 100% properly.

Comment: @JohnChurchill so, if we go with my approach, we have some unprobable, but possible cases that you were pointing to. Yet, the alternative that you prefer sacrifices a lot of performance by displaying all texts in order to render and letting the browser sort out which is the longest. If the grid contains many elements, maybe thousands or even more, then this will be felt in each use. So, what do we prefer: occasional glitches, or constant slowness? I go for the former and the only argument that could convince me for the latter would be the frequency of the problem.